# How to create date structure in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

On a exercise about **Data abstraction and immutable data**,I require to create a date structure using only numbers and functions. I also need to implement functions that print the components of the date.

**execution example:**

```
>>>d = make_date(2016, 12, 26)
>>>d
<function make_date.<locals>.dispatch at 0x02A880C0>
>>>year (d)
2016
>>>month (d)
December
>>> day (d)
26
>>> str_date(d)
'26th of December, 2016'
```

i dont understand the 3rd execution line..

```
<function make_date.<locals>.dispatch at 0x02A880C0>
```

can i get an example of code with such execution?

I only manged to get this ..

```
<function dispatch at 0x02CCE078>
```

Here is what I got so far:

```
def make_date(y,m,d):
    def year_f():
        nonlocal y
        return y
    def day_f():
        nonlocal d
        return d    
    def month_f():
        nonlocal m
        if(m==1):
            return 'January'
        if(m==2):
            return 'February' 
        if(m==3):
            return 'March'
        if(m==4) . . . 

    def dispatch(date_type):
        if date_type==1:
             return year_f
        if date_type==2:
            return month_f
        if date_type==3:
            return day_f 
    return dispatch
    #=================================================#
def year(p):
    return p(1)()
def month(p):
    return p(2)()
def day(p):
    return p(3)() 
def str_date(p):
    return repr("{0}th of {1}, {2}".format(day(p),month(p),year(p)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`make_date` returns a *function* object, you assign it to `d`.

When you print `d`, you get the representation of the function, which is expected

```
<function make_date.<locals>.dispatch at 0x02A880C0>
```

The generated function isn't called.

To get a result, you would have to call the function, simply like this: `d(<some params>)`

note the syntax in your snippet:

```
def year(p):
    return p(1)()
```

when you call `year(d)`, it does call `d(1)()` (calls your function with `1` as a parameter)

EDIT: that wasn't really answering the question. With the code you provided, I get

```
<function make_date.<locals>.dispatch at 0x000000000346A6A8>
```

(since `dispatch` is nested in `make_date`)

But that is running Python 3.4 (or higher)

In python 2 (removing `nonlocal` statements) or in python 3.2 (same code) you get `<function dispatch at 0x000000000341A510>`.

So to get the required output you would need to upgrade your version of python.

Comment: when i print d i get  <function dispatch at 0x02CCE078> without the make_date.<locals> part

Comment: see my edit. With the provided snippet it doesn't happen (I'm running python 3)

Comment: but in my code dispatch is nested in make_date and i dont get        <function make_date.<locals>.dispatch at 0x000000000346A6A8>

Comment: what's your version of Python? mine is Python 3.4.

Comment: im using 3.2.2 version, so it could be a version problem?

Comment: that would make sense. Since it does the same in Python 2.

Comment: i tried it on 3.4 and it worked..thanks for the help